# Destructor for hash table using chaining

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I have a hash table of nodes. In my constructor, I initialize every element of the hash table to NULL. My code compiles, but after the executable ends, it has the following error: 
"Debug Assertion Failed!" 
Program: /pathname/
File:f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp
line: 52

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

My Implementation for constructor and destructor:

```
// Constructor
Hash::Hash() {
    for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
        Hash_Table[i] = NULL; // Will be used to indicate an empty bucket
     } 
}
//
//
// Destructor
Hash::~Hash() {
    song* temp;
    song* temp_next;
    for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) { // For every bucket
        if(NULL != Hash_Table[i]) { // If the bucket is not already empty
            temp = Hash_Table[i];
            while(NULL != temp) {
                delete[] temp->artist;
                delete[] temp->title;
                delete[] temp->playlists;
                delete[] temp->album;
                temp_next = temp->next;
                delete temp;
                temp = temp_next;
            } // end while loop
            Hash_Table[i] = NULL;
        } // end if
    } // end for loop
    delete[] Hash_Table;
} // end destructor
```

Comment: Some of the pointers you are deleting must not be valid.  You could add some `cerr` trace to document the pointers and operations on them, see what's mismatched, but I suggest you use `std::unordered_map<>` or `std::map<>` and `std::string` - you'll find life much easier.

Comment: Show more code. What is the type of `Hash_Table`? In the code there is no `new` for it. `delete[]` here also seems unreasonable.

Comment: You need a debugger to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a proper destructor for `song` if you haven't already.  That is `delete temp` should call `song::~song`, which deletes all of the members of `song` other than `song->next`.

Your destructor for `Hash` then becomes:

```
Hash::~Hash() {
    song* temp;
    song* temp_next;
    for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) { // For every bucket
        temp = Hash_Table[i];
        while(NULL != temp) {
            temp_next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = temp_next;
        } // end while loop
        Hash_Table[i] = NULL;
    } // end for loop
} // end destructor
```

I also removed `delete[] Hash_Table`, because your constructor doesn't `new Hash_Table[]`.  You only want `delete[]` for arrays of objects you've called `new[]` on.

Without seeing your full class definition, though, it's hard to see for sure whether my suggestions are fully correct.  As others have suggested, you should consider using `map<>` or `unordered_map<>` as opposed to trying to roll your own hash.  Unless, of course, this is a homework assignment that requires you to.